# Creating range objects in python

Tags: python-3.5

Is there a way to create objects or tuples in python which represent range.

I need to check whether a variable is within some range.

e.g.
Instead of doing:

```
a = 2
if a > -1 and a < 5:
 print (a)
```

I would like to do:

```
if a in [-1, 5]:
 print(a)
```

Comment: `for a in range(5): print(a)` or `for a in range(2, 5): print(a)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the beauties of Python:

```
a=2
if -1 <= a <= 5:
    print(a)
```